# How to conduct optimisation in R when there are constraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I need to optimise the following `object` function. `qgpd` is from package `fExtremes`.

```
var.asym <- function(alpha1, alpha2, xi, beta, n){
  term11 <- alpha1*(1-alpha1)^(2*xi-1)
  term12 <- alpha1*(1-alpha1)^(xi-1)*(1-alpha2)^xi
  term22 <- alpha2*(1-alpha2)^(2*xi-1)
  Sigma <- matrix(c(term11, term12, term12, term22), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
  Sigma*beta^2/n
}

mop.jacob.inv <- function(alpha1, alpha2, xi, beta){
  term11 <- -qgpd(alpha1, xi, beta)/xi - beta*(1-alpha1)^xi*log(1-alpha1)/xi
  term12 <- qgpd(alpha1, xi, beta)/beta
  term21 <- -qgpd(alpha2, xi, beta)/xi - beta*(1-alpha2)^xi*log(1-alpha2)/xi
  term22 <- qgpd(alpha2, xi, beta)/beta
  jacob <- matrix(c(term11, term12, term21, term22), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
  jacob.inv <- solve(jacob)
  jacob.inv
}

var.asym2 <- function(alpha1, alpha2) var.asym(alpha1, alpha2, 0.2, 1, 1000)

mop.jacob.inv2 <- function(alpha1, alpha2) mop.jacob.inv(alpha1, alpha2, 0.2, 1)

# Function to be optimised:

object <- function(alpha1, alpha2){
  term1 <- mop.jacob.inv2(alpha1, alpha2)%*%var.asym2(alpha1, alpha2)%*%t(mop.jacob.inv2(alpha1, alpha2))
  sum(diag(term1))
}
```

To **minimise** `object`, I have an additional **constraint** of `0 < alpha1 < alpha2 < 1`. My question is whether I can do this using the generic `optim` function in `R`. If so, what is the syntax, i.e., how to set up the problem in `R`? And is there other and/or better way? If not, is there a way to do this in `R`? Thanks.

**Update:**

With the help in the comment, I have the following:

```
object <- function(alpha1, alpha2){
  term1 <- mop.jacob.inv2(alpha1, alpha2)%*%var.asym2(alpha1, alpha2)%*%t(mop.jacob.inv2(alpha1, alpha2))
  1/sum(diag(term1))*(alpha1>0)*(alpha2>alpha1)*(alpha2<1)
}

optim(c(0.01, 0.75), object)
```

Then I got error `Error in stopifnot(min(p, na.rm = TRUE) >= 0) : argument "alpha2" is missing, with no default`. What went wrong?

Comment: You can multiply `sum(diag(term1))` by `(alpha1>0)*(alpha2>alpha1)*(alpha2<1)` in a way that your objective function is 0 when a condition is not met. This should work if `object` is positive and you are looking for the maximum. If not, you can adjust the above factor accordingly.

Comment: @nicola Thanks. `object` indeed is positive. But I need to **minimise** it instead of maximising it. How do I adjust for this?

Comment: Just maximise `1/sum(diag(term1))` times the factor above.

Comment: @nicola I tried your method (see update in question). And I got error message `Error in stopifnot(min(p, na.rm = TRUE) >= 0) : argument "alpha2" is missing, with no default `. What is wrong?

Comment: Please, indicate always the packages you are using. I couldn't find the `qgpd` function. Is it from the `evir` package?

Comment: @nicola Sorry, it is from `fExtremes`. I forgot to say that.

Comment: See `?optim`. The function you are passing must have just one argument. Redefine `object<-function(pars) {alpha1<-pars[1];alpha2<-pars[2];...}` where the dots indicate the rest of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `constrOptim(...)` for this. We need to change the definition of `object` a bit.

```
object <- function(alpha){
  alpha1 <- alpha[1]
  alpha2 <- alpha[2]
  term1 <- mop.jacob.inv2(alpha1, alpha2)%*%var.asym2(alpha1, alpha2)%*%t(mop.jacob.inv2(alpha1, alpha2))
  sum(diag(term1))
}
ui <- matrix(c(1,0,-1,0,-1,1),nc=2)
ci <- c(0,-1,0)
result <- constrOptim(th=c(0.4,0.6),object, grad=NULL, ui=ui, ci=ci)
result$par
# [1] 1.962097e-10 7.962686e-01
```

The constraints are applied using the `ui=...` and `ci=...` arguments. `ui` is a `k x p` matrix where `p` is the number of parameters (2 in your case) and `k` is the number of constraints (3 in your case), and `ci` is a vector of length `k`. The constraints must be specified so that:

> ui × alpha - ci ≥ 0

So in your case the constraints are:

> α<sub>1</sub> ≥ 0
>
> -α<sub>2</sub> + 1 ≥ 0
>
> -α<sub>1</sub> + α<sub>2</sub> ≥ 0

The definitions of `ui` and `ci` in the code above enforce those constraints.

We can check the result using a grid search.

```
# check using grid search
x <- seq(0,1,by=0.1)
m <- expand.grid(a1=x,a2=x)
m <- m[m$a1<m$a2,]
grid <- apply(m,1,object)
m[which.min(grid),]
#    a1  a2
# 89  0 0.8
```

which yields a result very close to the optimized solution.

Comment: Thanks. I do get `m$a1<m$a2` in your code. I tried `which(m$a1<m$a2)` but did not get what I needed entries. What is the difference between the two. And how to use `which` in this case.

Comment: In this context they both do the same thing. The expression `m$a1<m$a2` returns a logical vector which elements are `TRUE` if the condition is met. Using a logical vector to index a data.frame returns the rows for which the index is `TRUE`. In contrast, `which(m$a1<m$a2)` returns an integer vector containing the row numbers which meet the condition. Using an integer vector to index a data.frame returns just those rows. In this case the two results are identical.